# MuleESB - Change Global Elements values at runtime

Tags: mule

I need to create a flow that makes queries, and I need to specify at runtime the jdbc connections.

I tried to use the Database Global Endpoint, but I can't specify runtime values in this way.
How can I do ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Which would you like to create dynamically: jdbc connectors or jdbc outbound endpoint queries?

For jdbc connectors perhaps you may create a component to add a connector to the [mule registry](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Storing+Objects+in+the+Registry)

For [dynamic outbound](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Configuring+Endpoints#ConfiguringEndpoints-DynamicEndpoints) jdbc endpoints, the query may be created at runtime using an expression.

HTH